# How do you traverse the Webpack module graph without `module.reasons`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-5

In Webpack 5, `module.reasons` was removed (see: https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/). From what I have been able to find, the documentation doesn't list an alternative. Documentation for the module graph is also pretty scarce.

We have build code that currently checks `module.reasons` inside of the `splitChunksPlugin` `test()` function. That code breaks in Webpack 5.

Does anyone know what the replacement for `module.reasons` is? I've tried looking stuff up in the module graph but I don't think the current module has been added yet because it is always undefined when calling `getModule()` on the graph.

Comment: I was able to get this working using the module graph. It has a method called `getIncomingConnections()` that you pass the current module into and get information about what is importing the current module.